# Can i disable default ordering in Django admin panel?

Tags: django, sorting, model, admin

I'm trying to use 'liczba_glosow' field for ordering in Django admin panel. The problem is that the model itself has ordering by "numer_na_liscie" in Meta method and admin uses default ordering and than 'liczba_glosow'. I would like admin to use ONLY order_by("-_liczba_glosow") and bypass default. I can't use simple ordering="liczba_glosow" because this field is created only for admin display purpose and it's not part of a model itself.

```
class KandydatDoSejmuAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("imie_nazwisko", "numer_na_liscie", "okreg_wyborczy", "komitet_wyborczy", "liczba_glosow")
    raw_id_fields = ("okreg_wyborczy", "komitet_wyborczy")
    list_filter = ("komitet_wyborczy__nazwa", "oddanyglos__kod_pocztowy__wojewodztwo", "okreg_wyborczy__nazwa",)
    search_fields = (
        "imie_nazwisko", "okreg_wyborczy__nazwa", "komitet_wyborczy__nazwa", "oddanyglos__kod_pocztowy__wojewodztwo")
    list_per_page = 10

    def liczba_glosow(self, obj):
        return obj.oddanyglos_set.count()

    liczba_glosow.admin_order_field = "_liczba_glosow"

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.annotate(
            _liczba_glosow=Count("oddanyglos__kandydat")
        ).order_by("-_liczba_glosow")
```

According to Django docs:

> Set ordering to specify how lists of objects should be ordered in the Django admin views. This should be a list or tuple in the same format as a model’s ordering parameter.
> If this isn’t provided, the Django admin will use the model’s default ordering.

According to the above provision, any attempt to disable the default sorting like ordering=None, get_ordering() returning None or empty list doesn't work.

Is there an option to override the default sorting in the admin panel without interfering with the model? I need the default sorting of the model in other parts of the application, so I would prefer to leave it.